# Are there any Google apps in the Mac App Store?

Tags: apple-silicon, compatibility

It seems like Google is not allowing any of its iOS or iPadOS apps to be installed on macOS (on ARM Macs) via the Mac App Store.  Are there any exceptions?

Comment: OK. I think the matching answer I provided is generally helpful info, so the downvotes are odd.  Seems personal.

Comment: Downvotes particularly odd given I just saw this: "
You've earned the "Popular Question" badge (Question with 1,000 views) for "Are there any Google apps in the Mac App Store?" "  Clearly this is a question that many people have, and it's answered here too.

Answer (score 0):

**No***.  There were some, but not currently (September 2023).
I went through all the apps in the Mac App Store on [Google's developer page](https://apps.apple.com/gd/developer/google-llc/id281956209?see-all=i-phonei-pad-apps)
and for every one, it shows "This app is available only on the App Store for iPhone and iPad."
(There are also some third-party apps that could be mistaken for Google apps.)

*But, some are available for direct download:
The Google apps that are available that run on macOS on ARM Macs include [Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/download/) and [Drive](https://www.google.com/drive/download/).  Gone are Meet, Sketchup, Picasa, Photos, and more.  (Unless you have an old version of macOS (11.2.3 or older version of Big Sur) or have some other tricks.) (Earth Pro (free) [is available *via Rosetta/for Intel*](https://www.google.com/earth/versions/#download-pro).)